# How can I show a String for only a few seconds in Java?

Tags: java, string, jframe

I would like to show a String for only 5 secs on the center of my JFrame.
How can I do it?

Comment: Thread.sleep(5000);Then set the text to "" and refresh the dialogue.

Comment: @JustinKSU that will freeze the whole application. It's not a good idea.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza good point.  You can do it in a separate thread then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a `JLabel` to your `JFrame`.
2. Set the text of the `JLabel`.
3. For waiting, don't use the Event Dispatch Thread on which you are when creating the UI elements. Use a Swing Timer instead: [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)
4. When the timer fires, set the text of the `JLabel` to the empty string or remove it entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. Technically, it is still a different thread that does the waiting although you don't create it explicitly. From the javax.swing.Timer javadoc: "Although all Timers perform their waiting using a single, shared thread (created by the first Timer object that executes), the action event handlers for Timers execute on another thread -- the event-dispatching thread. "

Comment: I agree, the waiting is done in a different thread, and out of sight, but I was afraid that with your answer the OP would try to get the Timer running in a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Swing question and so the solution is to use a Swing Timer not `Thread.sleep(...)`. If you use thread sleep, you will risk sleeping the Swing event thread, putting the entire GUI to sleep, preventing any new text from showing.